# В selenium не работает функция by

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#userProfileId > a")
driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/")

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)

button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign In")
button.click()
```

Не работает функция By, пишет, что такого имени не найдено, хотя в документации и во всех уроках работает(5 строчка в скобках)

Comment: в начале файла добавьте импорт `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало! Сколько дней уже сижу

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб использовать библиотечную функцию или класс нужно его импортировать.

В начале файла добавьте импорт

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```